# Finding Top Level Parent ID

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

In one table I have two columns like below

```
ID  ParentID
1   0x0
2   1
3   2
9   0x0
5   9
6   5
25  0x0
30  25
```

How to get top level parent ID
The result should look like

```
ID   TopParentID
3    1
6    9
30   25
```

Comment: Are you really working with 2005 version? You should consider upgrading it. Also, you might want to consider upgrading your question to change the "fancy" "buttons" to DDL+DML for sample data.

Comment: What is your desired output?  Do you want a table that lists the `ParentID` for each `ID` or are you specifying an `ID` and you want to return that `ParentID` only?

Comment: You *really* need to consider upgrading. All supported versions of SQL Server have the `hierarchyid` type which makes the `ID/ParentID` combination obsolete. The earliest supported version is 2012. 2005 is way, way past its End-Of-Life date

Comment: The client is using that version (2005) I can't do anything regarding this issue :(

Comment: Ah, clients.... If only we could make a living without them... :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yet another shorter CTE :

```
WITH cte AS(
      SELECT *, id AS topparent 
      FROM t 
      WHERE parentid IS NULL
  UNION ALL
      SELECT t.*, c.topparent 
      FROM t JOIN cte c ON c.id = t.parentid
      WHERE t.id <> t.parentid
)
SELECT * FROM cte
```

Tested here : [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d22c7d/3)

---

*EDIT* :  This damn SQLfiddle is unresponsive again. Test DDL Code below

```
CREATE  table t (id INT, parentid INT);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (1  , NULL );
INSERT INTO T VALUES (2  , 1    );           
INSERT INTO T VALUES (3  , 2    );          
INSERT INTO T VALUES (9  , NULL );          
INSERT INTO T VALUES (5  , 9    );          
INSERT INTO T VALUES (6  , 5    );          
INSERT INTO T VALUES (25 , NULL );          
INSERT INTO T VALUES (30 , 25   );
```

Comment: I like this one

Comment: You can use [rextester](http://rextester.com/l/sql_server_online_compiler)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *, 1 [Level]
    FROM dbo.YourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT A.ID, B.[Parent ID], [Level] + 1
    FROM CTE A
    INNER JOIN dbo.YourTable B
        ON A.[Parent ID] = B.Id
), CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [Level] DESC)
    FROM CTE
    WHERE [Parent ID] <> 0
)
SELECT ID, [Parent ID] [Top Level Parent Id]
FROM CTE2
WHERE RN = 1
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
;
```

**[Here is a link with a demo](http://rextester.com/VHXE97763)**.

The results are:

```
╔════╦═════════════════════╗
║ ID ║ Top Level Parent Id ║
╠════╬═════════════════════╣
║  2 ║                   1 ║
║  3 ║                   1 ║
║  5 ║                   9 ║
║  6 ║                   9 ║
║ 30 ║                  25 ║
╚════╩═════════════════════╝
```

Comment: I don't think SQL Server 2005 had the `OVER` clause

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Well, it does

Answer (score 0):

If the top-level node always follows a single path to a single leaf node, then the desired result can be achieved by combining Breadcrumbs and recursive CTEs. The following example demonstrates the approach:

```
CREATE TABLE #Items
(
    ID              INT
    ,[ParentID]     INT
)

INSERT INTO #Items
VALUES
(1,     0x0),
(2,     1),
(3,     2),
(9,     0x0),
(5,     9),
(6,     5),
(25,    0x0),
(30,    25)



;WITH CTE_Breadcrumbs
AS
(
    SELECT      ID
                ,ParentID
                ,CAST(ID AS NVARCHAR(1000)) AS [Path]
                ,LEN(CAST(ID AS NVARCHAR(1000))) AS [PathLength]
                ,ID AS [RootNodeID]
    FROM        #Items
    WHERE       ParentID = 0x0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT       Child.ID
                ,Child.ParentID
                ,CAST(Parent.[Path] + N'\' + CAST(Child.ID AS NVARCHAR(1000)) AS NVARCHAR(1000)) AS [Path]
                ,LEN(CAST(Parent.[Path] + N'\' + CAST(Child.ID AS NVARCHAR(1000)) AS NVARCHAR(1000))) AS [PathLength]
                ,CAST(
                    CASE 
                        WHEN CHARINDEX('\', [Path]) > 0 THEN LEFT([Path], CHARINDEX('\', [Path]) - 1)
                        ELSE Child.ParentID
                    END
                AS INT)  AS [RootNodeID]
    FROM        #Items Child 
    INNER JOIN  CTE_Breadcrumbs Parent ON Child.ParentID = Parent.ID
)
,
CTE_FullPathID
AS
(
    SELECT      [RootNodeID]
                ,MAX([PathLength]) AS [PathFullLength]
    FROM        CTE_Breadcrumbs
    GROUP BY    [RootNodeID]

)
SELECT      CTE_Breadcrumbs.RootNodeID
            ,CAST(
                REVERSE(
                            CASE 
                                WHEN CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE([Path])) > 0 THEN LEFT(REVERSE([Path]), CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE([Path])) - 1)
                                ELSE NULL
                            END
                        )
            AS INT)  AS [LeafNodeID]
            ,CTE_Breadcrumbs.[Path]
FROM        CTE_Breadcrumbs 
INNER JOIN  CTE_FullPathID ON CTE_Breadcrumbs.[RootNodeID] = CTE_FullPathID.[RootNodeID] AND CTE_Breadcrumbs.PathLength = CTE_FullPathID.[PathFullLength]
```